# r, cbind two columns, values in specifi order

Tags: r, cbind

I have 2 lists, one with Gender `c('m', 'f', 'f', 'm', 'f')`, the other with names `c('Peter', 'Peter', 'Anna', 'Anna', 'Peter')`.
I want to `join` / `merge` the two columns to a data frame, where the sex-values are suitable to the names (Peter with m, Anna with f).

How to I do this in R?

Thanks for helping guys!

Comment: How should R know that Peter is male and Anna female? Without any information to match the names to the genders you have to do this manually, i.e. put the names in a df and add a new column using e.g. something like `df$gender <- ifelse(df$name %in% c("Peter"), "m", "f")` or make use of a look-up table which gives the sex for each name.

Answer (score 1):

Another option with `unnest`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
tibble(gender, names) %>%
    unnest(c(gender, names))
```

#### data

```
gender <- list(c('m', 'f', 'f', 'm', 'f'))
names <- list(c('Peter', 'Peter', 'Anna', 'Anna', 'Peter'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have the following two lists:

```
gender = list(c('m', 'f', 'f', 'm', 'f'))
names = list(c('Peter', 'Peter', 'Anna', 'Anna', 'Peter'))
```

One option would be to use `unlist` and combine them into a `data.frame`:

```
data.frame(names = unlist(names),
           gender = unlist(gender)
           )

#   names gender
# 1 Peter     m
# 2 Peter     f
# 3 Anna      f
# 4 Anna      m
# 5 Peter     f
```